# trigger an event when GC start

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

hi one small question in c#,
is this possible to trigger an event whenever Garbage Collector Start working?

if yes, how?

imagine this code:

```
while(True){

    if (Gc.IsWorking())
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

running on a separate thread and detect when gc is working.
i know that when gc triggered the whole application will pause , but can we some how disable it for some part of code like using **unsafe** so that way we can have that thread working?

Comment: Have you experienced any actual issue? GC pauses should be short enough not to notice for most applications. And if you have issues, the first step should be to look at your memory allocations. A well designed program should have either long lived allocations (gen 2), or very short lived ones (i.e. gen 0/1). If this is done correctly you should mostly get very fast gen 0 collections. So this really sounds like an X/Y issue.

Comment: @JonasH not really its not x/y problem ,i know the pauses are short.  im not facing any issue , just wondering if this is possible or not ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) that can pause the GC. But this is for very specialized scenarios where you need very low and predictable latency. I think the intent is to have a rotating set of live nodes, and do any GC when nodes are rotated offline.

It might also be possible to use native code. I would not expect the GC to know or care about native threads.

But neither are solutions that should be used in any common scenario. Optimizing your allocation patterns will likely be sufficient for 99% of use cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the case. see imagine your web api is serving 20 request per second. best case scenario you would have a 1 micro second delay for gc. 
i just want to know if a user sent request in that time , can i notify him that im doing gc ( i know i should not say that to him ) or not

Comment: @AliSalehi In the best case scenario you would have no GC delay, since the GC only run when needed. And even if you have a 1us GC delay, informing the client will take far more time than just waiting for the GC to finish and serve the request. If you are super sensitive to latency you could have a rotating set of servers set to no gc mode, but that would be rare outside of High frequency trading scenarios.

Comment: so i cannot know then gc start. tnx

Comment: @AliSalehi there are profiling APIs that probably have such events, But your listener would probably have to be a separate process, since your threads are by definition paused during a GC pause. So any attempt at "do X during a GC pause" is likely misguided.